# How to give user role without manage role permission in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm planning on allowing users to add a reaction or type a command to be assigned a role. How do I assign a role **without the user requiring the manage roles permission**?

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='m.')
token = 'a token goes here'


@client.command()
async def hello_world(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello world!")


client.run(token)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='m.')
token = 'a token goes here'


@client.command()
async def player(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "player")
    if role is not None:
       await ctx.author.add_roles(role)


client.run(token)
```

You need to have the `player` role in your server too. The user sends `m. player` as example and the bot gives him that role.

Comment: Please consider following the [PEP8 Style Guide](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#programming-recommendations) and use `if role is not None:` instead of `if role!=None:`